# What are the Python networking alternatives for this example?

Tags: python, networking

I have an environment with up to 10 workstations and one server all sitting in the same physical location. They will be running some proprietary Python scripts that will need to talk to each other:

- server script on server with client scripts on workstations;
- server script on workstation with client scripts on other workstations;
- server script on workstation with client script on same workstation.

So all in all, as far as the actual communication goes, its very nature is more towards the informal on-the-fly kind rather than a fixed client/server relationship.

The data itself will be of a few different sorts, ranked in order of bandwidth demands:

- realtime-ish datafeed (it can be made less frequent if needed) with no real demands of high quality transfer;
- 100% realtime and with high demands of transfer integrity;
- messages with once every minute or so frequency.

The transmitted data units are all small in size, counted in kilobytes at most.

As this is my first time using Python's networking capabilities, what are the different ways of doing this? I did some research myself but I was taken aback by the plethora of networking/messaging packages in the Python universe, so I thought I'd rather ask the community for some guidance.

Please list pros and cons to each alternative. If I'd rank the 'wish list' it'd be something like this:

- has to offer high as well as low data integrity modes;
- easy to deploy/develop/maintain;
- high performance but not too low-level;
- small resource footprint;
- plays well with Qt/PySide;
- platform independent.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into RabbitMQ ([www.rabbitmq.com](http://www.rabbitmq.com)).  This would allow you to setup your server as a RabbitMQ messaging server and use the message queue protocol to communicate between your servers and workstations.  The biggest advantage here is you don't really have to worry about the networking at all.

Otherwise, I know Twisted is a popular Python library for networking (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: What makes RabbitMQ different from the other MQs? And is any one of them better from a Python perspective?

Comment: I don't have experience with others to compare it to, but RabbitMQ is supported on just about every platform and has client libraries in just about every language and is open source.  The tutorials are in Python so that would lead me to believe that the Python support is strong - thus far I've been using it in Scala over the JVM and it's working quite well and was extremely easy to setup, especially if you're just using it over a secure local network and don't need SSL/etc.